# how to get the state value in react after setting it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below code I am trying to set a react state country and I need to use it immediately after setting. right now I am getting only the previous state value in the country variable. is there any way to get the country value immediately after setting? like callback or promise?

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';


const url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/'
let renderData= <div id="result"><h4>no Data </h4></div>

const Search = () =>
{

const [country,setCountry]=useState('');
const setCountryState = () =>
{   
    setCountry(event.target.value);
   somefunction(country); //I am calling Some Other function Here by passing country as variable
}

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
            <input type="text" value={country} onChange={setCountryState} placeholder="Country Name"/>
            </form>
            <div>
            {country}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState async so it does not get updated immediately.

Instead, utilize useEffect and add country as a dependency. Every time country changes the useEffect function will run

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';


const url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/'
let renderData= <div id="result"><h4>no Data </h4></div>

const Search = () =>
{

const [country,setCountry]=useState('');

useEffect(()=>{
    somefunction(country)
},[country])

const setCountryState = (event) =>
{   
    setCountry(event.target.value);
}

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
            <input type="text" value={country} onChange={setCountryState} placeholder="Country Name"/>
            </form>
            <div>
            {country}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Search;
```